# Change height of elements in TableRow

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I made a TableLayout consisting of TableRows, in turn consisting of Buttons. I want to change the height of the ALL the buttons in the table layout to a fixed quantity (Basically increasing the height of each row).

It seems simple, but the only way i found was to set change the height attribute of every button.

This seems very tedious. Is there an efficient method to achieve this?

EDIT: the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.calculator.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="HEY!"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/numbers"
        />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="70dp">
            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/seven"
                android:text="7" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eight"
                android:text="8" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nine"
                android:text="9"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:text="DEL"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/four"
                android:text="4"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/five"
                android:text="5"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/six"
                android:text="6" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/divide"
                android:text="/"/>
        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set height of your TableRow to your desire one, and set height of button to `match_parent`

Comment: But according to the android documentation : "....However, the layout_height attribute can be defined by a child; default value is WRAP_CONTENT. If the child is a TableRow, then the height is always WRAP_CONTENT."

Comment: if you define by child you have to apply it to every child but if you assign it to parent and use `match_parent`  the same value will be inherit...if you can please post your TableRow xml code....

Comment: so i can see it worked as you wanted ..right ?